# Query in NodeJS with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I got this code and I need to create another query to send data in a form.... I tried copying this one but it didn't work .... 
any idea how to proceed ?.

```
    app.get('/', function (req2, res2) {
    console.log('Welcome in console');

    var sqlQuery = 'select * from transvip.transvip_regions';
    // var sqlQuery2 = 'select * from transvip.transvip_agreement_favourite_address';


    connection.query(sqlQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;

        //console.log("results in console: ");
        //console.log(results);

        res.render('home', {
            title: "Rounting and Assignment Grouped Trips",
            results: results
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting any console error
did you printed your result before rendering into view

Comment: what you mean 'didnt work'? show the error log....

Comment: My mistake, sorry, it works but I want to replicate this to load another table of the db .... (mysql)